# TexShop can't open my bibliograhy

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have to do a bibliography so I created a document .bib and I put this code:

```
@misc{ref1,
author = {Commission de la Formation et de la Vie Universitaire de Toulouse},
title = {Délibération 2016/06/CFVU-38}, 
date = {2016}, 
organization = {Université Toulouse 3}
}
```

In my latex document I've called this bibliography with

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibliographie}
```

But when I want to compile, the console says [image]

Comment: You do not run the compilation on your `.bib` file. Instead run LaTeX (or your favourite LaTeX flavour: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX) on your main `.tex` file and then run BibTeX and finally LaTeX again (twice to be sure all cross references are OK). For your editor that probably means that your `.tex` file needs to be in focus/selected for all compilation operations. You do not compile/run programms on the `.bib` file. More background is explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864.

Comment: Thanks it's work